# S3 bucket policy - Font not displaying on website

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3

Hi i am trying to get data from s3 on my site, every thing is working good, but fonts are not displaying. Here is my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from 54.148.239.58",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/*",
                        "http://54.148.239.58/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:-
http://54.148.239.58/s3_file_exit_ck1.php?link=663&page=4

I don't know what am i doing wrong.

If i remove https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/* from policy .svg files don't display.

But this is not working,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ZapfDingbatsStd_2b4;
    src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/htmlmanuals/663/fonts/ZapfDingbatsStd_2b.woff") format("woff");
}
```

it work on localhost.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the console in my web browser, when I access your page it triggers an error message:

> Font from origin 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://54.148.x.x' is therefore not allowed access.

It appears that a page from one domain (`s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`) is trying to reference data from another domain (`54.148.x.x`). This is triggering **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** checks within the browser.

You will need to configure CORS rules to permit access.

From the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) documentation:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) defines a way for client web applications that are loaded in **one domain** to interact with resources in a **different domain**. With CORS support in Amazon S3, you can build rich client-side web applications with Amazon S3 and **selectively allow cross-origin access** to your Amazon S3 resources.

You'll need to add a policy to your S3 bucket to allow pages from `54.148.x.x` to access bucket resources.